# Electron - Disable Cookie Security policies

Tags: electron, chromium

I've turned off `{ webSecurity: false }` from `webPreferences`
There's a site I'm doing a HTTP request and its returning me some cookies to be set.
But the issue is the cookie has some policies which is preventing to set.

```
This Set-Cookie header didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was defaulted to "SameSite-Lax," and was blocked because it came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with "SameSite=None" to enable cross-site usage.
```

How do I disable all cookie related security policies on electron (Chromium).